# Online service to transform coordinates from WGS84 to NZTM and NZMG?

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, web-service, new-zealand

Has anyone come across a free web service / REST API to transform coordinates?

I'm particularly interested in transforming from WGS84 to: New Zealand Geodetic Datum 2000 (NZGD2000 / NZTM) and New Zealand Geodetic Datum 1949 (NZGD1949 / NZMG). Would be a bonus if I could also get the grid version of coordinates as well.

Perhaps there's a JavaScript / C# library out there that I can use and host my own service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Proj4JS](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) to do the conversion in the browser: either pass it EPSG codes ([EPSG:2193](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2193/) for NZGD 2000, [EPSG:27200](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27200) for NZGD 1949). They have [a user guide](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/UserGuide) with further details of its configuration.

Comment: Thanks scw - perfect fit once I used WGS84 as the source instead of EPSG:4236 they gave in their example code.

Comment: perhaps let them know they have a typo, I'm guessing they meant to put EPSG:4326 which is the correct code for WGS84.

Comment: They have both EPSG:4326 and WGS84 - seem to be slighly different definitions though.

Comment: But yes, does look like a typo on example. Was getting confused myself! Can't find any contact options or registration options to get in contact with the project creators though to let them know.

Comment: Note that Proj4JS doesn't use the grid-based conversion, so its accuracy is limited to +/- 4m [according to LINZ](http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/geodetic-datum-conversion/nzgd1949-nzgd2000/three-and-seven-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

I use http://apps.linz.govt.nz/coordinate-conversion/ all the time...

Comment: Link broken, fyi

Answer (score -1):

You should really just use this site its much easier than the others unless you wish to do this within your java code:

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2193&t_srs=4326